# How would i get the JSON data from a response like this in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have created a function the queries an API as such:

```
public function get_item($item_id = NULL)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $url_string = $this->base_api."/item/".$item_id.$this->after_item;
        //https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0//item/8705967.json?print=pretty
        $response = $client->get($url_string);
        return $response;
    }
```

Here is the response that I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Length: 385 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Cache-Control: no-cache 

{ "by" : "theuser", "id" : 8705967, "parent" : 8705928, "text" : "I've done them all. Here's my writeup on the pros/cons of each: http://awebsite.com/the-definitive-guide-to-pro...", "time" : 1417804054, "type" : "comment" }
```

How would I handle this sort of data? To be able to have it in array and manipulate it that is.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I handle this sort of data?

You need to distinguish the header from the body of the response. Something like:

```
$data = json_decode(end(explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2)), true);
```

But maybe you want that your Client::get function only return the body of the response.